# Accept only y or yes with a one-line regular expression

Tags: regular-expression

I want to check if an input is y or yes (inputs in lowercase) and reject everything else

What I have now is `^y[e]{'0,1'}[s]['0,1']$`

But this accepts `y`, `ye`, `ys`, `yes`. I don't want `ye` and `ys` to be accepted.

Comment: What flavour of regular expression (basic, extended, GNU basic, perl, vim, AT&T augmented...)? What will you use that with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only accept two possibilities, you can explicitly state them:

```
^y$\|^yes$
```

or, depending on what you mean by "without making another conditional statement", you can use:

```
^y(es)?$
```

The `?` is equivalent to `{'0,1'}` and the parentheses groups the `es` characters together.

Comment: Great. If this solved your problem, "select" it by clicking on the gray checkmark below the up- and down-toggles next to the answer.